# How to control fps with requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, three.js, requestanimationframe

I have used FBX format with three js. It seems like requestAnimationFrame is the de facto way to animate things now. The animation was working very speed, Like lightening. Can't find any solutions to control the fps.

See the below image.

[image: jet]

Source code:

```
if (!Detector.webgl)
 Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, stats, controls;
var camera, scene, renderer, light, mesh;

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var mixers = [];

var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
var spdx = 0, spdy = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
 var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);

scene = new THREE.Scene();

// grid
var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(28, 28, 0x303030, 0x303030);
gridHelper.position.set(0, -0.04, 0);
scene.add(gridHelper);

// stats
stats = new Stats();
container.appendChild(stats.dom);

// model
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
    console.log(item, loaded, total);
};

var onProgress = function (xhr) {
    if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
    }
};
var onError = function (xhr) {
    console.error(xhr);
};

var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader(manager);
loader.load('assests/JetEngine_Ani.fbx', function (object) {
    object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
    mixers.push(object.mixer);
    var action = object.mixer.clipAction(object.animations[ 0 ]);
    action.play();
    scene.add(object);

}, onProgress, onError);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd, 1);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.target.set(0, 12, 0);
camera.position.z = 850;
controls.update();

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444, 1.0);
light.position.set(0, 1, 0);
scene.add(light);
light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
light.position.set(0, 1, 0);
scene.add(light); }


 function onWindowResize() {
  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);  }

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
 }
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (mixers.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
        mixers[ i ].update(clock.getDelta());
    }
}
stats.update();
render();
}
function render() {

renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

> How to control the animation speed. Is there have other ways or only through fps(frames per second).
>
> How can I reduce the animation speed??..

Comment: You can control the animation in relation to time with `performance.now()`.

Comment: What does your `stats.update` do? Maybe you need to pass `clock.getDelta()` as well and use it?. You should program in a way, that the FPS don't change the animation speed.

Comment: Try `action.setDuration( 10 ).play();`

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you man.. It's working. Could you post this as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to control the duration of your `AnimationAction` loop. To do so, you can use this pattern:

```
action.setDuration( 10 ).play();
```

three.js r.87